# Getting list of local IP addresses with winapi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking, network-programming

How to get a list of all local IP addresses connected to the LAN using WINAPI? I searched through netapi32.dll and haven't been successful. Any thoughts ?

Comment: You mean multiple IP addresses of the current machine, or IP addresses of all machines in LAN/Domain?

Comment: IP addresses of all machines in LAN.

Comment: When you get the IP of your machine and the network mask, you can calculate the addresses of the other machines.

Comment: @Mayhem That is interesting, but how is it done? Could you write me a code, or recommend a tutorial ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no guaranteed way to get the addresses of all devices connected to your local segment. Machines may be firewalled and dropping requets, or have IP addresses in different subnets that the checking machine isn;t configured to access.

You can find all devices on the subnet that respond to a ping by sending a ping request (using `ICMPSendEcho()` in the IP Helper library) to every IP address on the local subnet and check for responses.

Comment: IIRC, you can perform a broadcast ICMP ping?

Comment: @MartinJames Technically yes, but I don't think windows natively supports it. It may require raw sockets and manually createing the ICMP packets.