# How to get a list of all IP addresses in the LAN?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

Is it possible to get a list of all connected ip addresses in the LAN and how it can be done using winapi?

Comment: _SCAN_ - Ping the all addresses which are in your subnet mask and collect alive devices.

Comment: Isn't ICMP by default blocked by the firewall with recent windows versions?

Comment: another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508623/getting-list-of-local-ip-addresses-with-winapi

Comment: Did I miss the question, or is the OP simply asking how to apply the subnet mask to a LAN address to determine the network-portion and generate a list of all possible IP addresses within that network? Where did he say anything about *connected* host addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Hosts may choose not to respond to ICMP/PING requests.  However, you could figure out your own IP address and subnet mask, then iterate through the possibilities and run Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) broadcast requests on them.  Hosts have to respond to those for normal networking to function.  If you get back MAC address responses, you've got a match for that IP address.  Check out `SendARP` are Windows...